# Can't ping own machine using public IP or registered domain name

Tags: networking, server

I try to ping my newly set up Ubuntu 18 server (running as VPS at some hosting provider) from the command line after I ssh into the machine. Both when using the public IP address (`196.189.91.144`) or the registered domain name (`swapme.et`) the just ping times out.

As I am a bit ignorant when it comes to server configuration, I'm lost and surprised this is not working, especially since I haven't had the same issue on previous VPS-servers I have fiddled with.

Do I need to do some extra manual configuration to get the loopback working? I thought it was possible to ping yourself using the public IP or domain name, out of the box(?)

This is what I have right now and what I can think of is relevant info for the solving the problem:

#### /etc/hostname

`etisp`

#### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

#### $ ifconfig -a

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.180.53.144  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.180.53.255
        inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe43:32d6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:16:3e:43:32:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4478573  bytes 324094022 (324.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 279023  bytes 41316618 (41.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 730566  bytes 43043266 (43.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 730566  bytes 43043266 (43.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

#### Firewall rules

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Note that pinging other servers is working and pinging the public ip address and domain name from another machine is working

Thanks!

Comment: and what firewall rules is this machine using? You host should be able to tell you what the defaults configurations are per the vps!

Comment: I think it is more a problem with your routing, than your system. The system knows `10.180.53.144` and answering it. The router (NAT?) knows the internal net `10.180.53.0/32` and the external IP `196.189.91.144`. If a ICMP request (ping) on `196.189.91.144` hit the router, it will be translated (not forwarded!) to `10.180.53.144`. But a request from the internal net about the external IP needs rules, depending on your setup.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. @LupusE - Could you elaborate on how to check my setup to determine what rules are needed? Sorry, I'm lost here :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. @George Udosen - I Added firewall rules to the question.

Comment: @Claudijo, it is not that simple. Because we really don't know your setup. Regarding your question I assume we don't talk about a enterprise environment. Everything could be the needed information. You've already described your system in a good summary. But not the router and the type of internet connection. The system could be in a rack, standing at a provider as well as in the basement or office at home. I do think the missed information is the type and configuration of the internet-connected router.

Comment: @LupusE, are your referring to some external router hardware? I really don't know about that. The VPS is hosted by a monopolized governmental telcom in a developing former communist country. Expected help from their support is little to none :-/

Comment: Just keep it simple. There is a system with the IP `10.180.53.144`. It should have a LAN cable plugged in. There is another device on the other end. This Device should be in the net `10.180.53.0/32` and know the external IP `196.189.91.144`. The other side of the cable from the interface `196.189.91.144` goes to an outlet in a wall and we don't have access to any infrastructure, behind. And maybe there is also a switch, a hub or another router between the outlet and the Interface `10.180.53.144`?

Comment: (it is /24 not /32 ... why nobody correcting me?)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what we are knowing so far, I'll try a first solution.
[image]

- There is the Server, that is send a Ping to the external Address `196.189.91.144`
- There is the router, that knows the net `10.180.53.0/24` including `10.180.53.144` and the external IP `196.189.91.144`
- There is the Internet, that knows the external IP `196.189.91.144`

If anyone from the Internet will ping the external IP, maybe the router will answer or in advanced configuration the ICMP will be forwarded and die server will answer. We don't know yet.

But in any case, the router needs the information, to answer requests from the external address on the internal interface, too.
Every route, that is not defined, will go though the standard gateway, in this case the router. But the router has a default gateway (most times the provider), too. And if the router send a ping to the provider, why should the provider answer it?

The options to handle it are depending on the exact setup. But in any case, why do I need to check the ICMP response of a system behind the NAT, from behind the NAT? There is the internal network more important.

Comment: Thanks again @LupusE for taking the time and explaining a network topology. However, I have very low hopes on getting info from the provider about the physical setup around the VPS, as mentioned in previous comment. I was hoping there was a software configuration I could do on the server.

Comment: The reason I need this is to work is because I run a server side rendered web site and a bunch of micro services on the server, and if the server is rendering the web page it is set up in such a way that it will under some circumstances make http requests to a micro service hosted on the same machine. Which is obviously not working as the server is not able to reach itself, not when using the external IP, nor when using the domain name. Anyhow, I noticed that if I add `swapme.et` pointing to 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts` it works as expected. Not sure if this is the right way™ to do it though...

Comment: If it's on the same meachine, you can just call localhost:port -- you don't need to go the slow route.